# Injecting Custom HTML into Google Drive UI

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to inject custom code/html into the latest Google Drive UI?

The other day I was shown a Google Drive UI that had a custom button embedded in the page. I've search through documentation and can't find anything that details how to do this...maybe it's something only Google Partners can or are allowed to do?!?

Comment: I'm pretty sure rather than injecting into the Google Drive UI, they wrote their own and implemented Google Drive functionality through the [Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk).

Comment: Yeah, I thought that until I saw the url was the normal https://drive.google.com/a/.....you can see the page here [link]https://www.aodocs.com/features/virtual-file-server/google-integration/ You can see there is a "WorkFlow" button at the top

Comment: my guess would be a chrome extension that patches the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a Chrome Extension that manipulates the DOM.

There is not a supported mechanism for you to inject custom HTML into the Drive UI, so any work-arounds you do (such as an extension) will break as we change the UI.

You can however register a web app to be included in the 'New' menu a la Google Docs and you can also register as file handles in the 'Open With' menu. Have a glance in the ['Integration with the Drive UI'](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/enable-sdk) docs

Comment: Dan :: I am trying to manipulate DOM via Chrome extension. However Drive has been upgraded to HTML 5 so It is hard to pin point the element. Any ideas on this?